# How to Iterate through OracleDbType.RefCursor result set

Tags: .net, oracle, c#-4.0, ref-cursor

I am currently a little stuck right now in my implementation of MVC 2 website that gets data from an Oracle Database... Right now I want to Iterate through a RefCursor out parameter and go threw all of the results and serialize it into a customized xml string...

Am I missing something about RefCursor?  Because after doing some resesarch there doesn't seem to be a way to loop throw all the returned Rows and Columns.  I know you can get a DataReader from a RefCursor... But DataReader seems to be somewhat confusing.  I just want to go through all the rows and columns of the returned data set... I wish the stored proc designer would have just returned the result set instead of placing it into a freaking Ref Cursor.  I am sure she had her reasons though.

This question does seem a little bush league and I will continue to research the best way to do this.  Thanks for any information that you can give...  Also, I am open to doing this in a completely different way.  I am not particularly wedded to any one way of looping through the ref cursor.

P.S Looks like I was using the depreciated way in my code.  Any idea on how to do it using ODP.Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this link: http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_return_result_set.html gives the answer you want.  You use a dataadapter to 'fill' a datatable with the refcursor result of the function.  Then you can iterate over the datatable.

Although looking at it closer I don't see how the author makes an associate between the 'out' refcursor parameter and the table mapping 'emp'.